# How to ping UDP in php

Tags: php, networking, tcp, udp, ping

I have a question about pinging certain game servers to see if they are alive or not, most work fine with just your standard PHP ping but others are from steam... and steam is making it more difficult for me to just send a ping to see if it is alive or not, i tried Steam Condenser but... have no idea how to use it since there is no documentation.

**my question**

how can i ping UDP game servers such as Arma 2, Arma 3, etc. this is what i tried:

```
        $host = '128.0.0.1';
        $port =  1234; 
        $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 7; 
        if($fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host,$port,$errCode,$errStr))
        {   
           echo 'Online'; 
        }
        else
        {
           echo 'Offline';
        }
```

the problem with that is that i always get "true" returned no matter what IP or port i use, how can i make this work?

**EDIT**
I also tried

```
        $host = '128.0.0.1';
        $port = 1234; 
        $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 7; 
        if($fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host,$port,$errCode,$errStr))
        {
            $write = fwrite($fp,"x00");
            if (!$write)
            { 
            echo 'offline';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'online'; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
           echo 'offline';
        } 
        fclose($fp);
```

however with this one i get error code 0 which seems to be a problem with the initializing of the socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one, by removing the "udp://" :

```
 $host = '128.0.0.1';
 $port =  1234; 
 $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 7; 
 if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr))
 {   
    echo 'Online'; 
 }
 else
 {
    echo 'Offline';
 }
```

And it works. Here is the return text :

Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 128.0.0.1:1234 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6
Offline

It don't think you should put the "udp://" because just using the port number is enough.

Comment: But that is how you tell it is UDP or else it defaults to TCP.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the OS's ping utility, execute terminal ping command using PHP. You can read it here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: The ping utility does not allow you to ping specific port on you remote server